# Ignore spaces in redirected output in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, du

I want to sort files by size in descending order, and list them next to their size in human-readable form.
So what I did is:

```
find $arg -type f -print -exec du -a {} + | sort -nr | head -11 | tail -10 | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | xargs du -h
```

And output:

```
3.7G    /path/to/file.iso
400M    /path/to/file2.iso
du: cannot access '/path/to/friends': No such file or directory
```

Because the full name of friends in this example is:

```
/path/to/friends\ 1_1.mp4
```

How can I deal with these issues?
And also is the better way to do the job?

Comment: Please explain the problem you are trying to solve, than asking what's wrong with your attempt.

Comment: @MortezaJ : I know "sorting by collating sequence" and "sorting by numeric value", but "sorting by pretty way" is new to me. I think it would not hurt if you explained what this term means.

Comment: @oguz ismail, Thank to you. The issue is solved now

Comment: @user1934428, pretty way certainly means my ideal way as I show the output in question. :)

Comment: I don't understand from the output (which contains just two lines) what your ideal way is. It looks like simple alphanumeric sort based on the first field in the lines (since '3' comes before '4' in ASCII, but '.'  would come after '2').

Comment: @Inian, the main issue is `du: cannot access '/path/to/friends': No such file or directory
` where you can find spaces in files. so the we have error in output .

Comment: @user1934428 Apparently *I want to sort only files in size by pretty way.* means *I want to sort regular files by size, and list them with their sizes in human-readable form*.

Comment: I see. So this means "sort **descending** by size given in human readable form". Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @user1934428 yes that's right. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all utilities in GNU coreutils package have an option for changing line terminator to NUL (either `-z` or `-0`), you can use them to avoid dealing with spaces, special characters, etc in input lines. And the sort utility from that package can sort human-readable numbers as well; so, you don't even need xargs and the second du here.

```
find "$arg" -type f -exec du -0ha {} + \
| sort -zhr  \
| head -zn11 \
| tail -zn10 \
| tr '\0' '\n'
```